# Is it possible to Update the Build Definition name using YAML in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to update Build definition name based on the YAML runtime parameters. I am able to achieve this like below

```
name: ${{ parameters.source }} to ${{ parameters.target }} $(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)
```

But I want to update the build name by providing conditional expressions. 
Please let me know if this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

`${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}: 
    stageName: prod`

Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) link for full list of expressions you can use.

Comment: Will this work for Build definition name? I know how to use conditional expressions in stages and jobs. but want to use the conditional expression to update the build definition name.

Comment: stageName is a variable. So, you can use condition to set the variable value and use it to set the name. Try it.

Comment: I tried this and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. But, now I am unable to append another variable without any expression

Comment: Share the code please. If the answer worked for you, could you accept it as answer and upvote it.

Comment: `variables:
  ${{ if and(eq(parameters.Target1, true), ne(parameters.Target2, true), eq(parameters.Target3, true)) }}: 
    target: Target1 and Target3
- group: processVariables
name: ${{ parameters.source }} to ${{ variables.target }} - $(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)`

Here getting an error at the variable group definition, not sure how to handle this

Comment: Could you please when asking question, try to give as much info as possible. In this case, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) that describes how to set the *run (build) number.*

If defining your own variable, My.Variable, reference it the run number as:

```
$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Build.DefinitionVersion)_$(Build.RequestedFor)_$(Build.BuildId)_$(My.Variable)
```